# Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro

Tags: spring-integration

I'm play with spring-integration-kafka component and when try to startup my context i retrive the following error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1ae8bcbc': 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 3 of type [org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer]: 
Could not convert constructor argument value of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder] 
to required type [org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer]: Failed to convert value of type 'org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder' 
to required type 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroReflectDatumBackedKafkaEncoder] 
to required type [org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

My bean definition is :

```
int-kafka:producer-context id="kafkaProducerContext" producer-properties="producerProperties">
    <int-kafka:producer-configurations>
        <int-kafka:producer-configuration broker-list="localhost:9092"
                key-class-type="java.lang.String"
                value-class-type="org.springframework.integration.samples.kafka.user.User"
                topic="test1"
                value-serializer="kafkaSpecificEncoder"
                key-serializer="kafkaReflectionEncoder"
                partitioner="customPartitioner"/>
```

where kafkaSpecificEncoder is declared like this :

```
<bean id="kafkaSpecificEncoder" class="org.springframework.integration.kafka.serializer.avro.AvroSpecificDatumBackedKafkaEncoder">
    <constructor-arg value="org.springframework.integration.samples.kafka.user.User" />
</bean>
```

User obj is Autogenerated from avro. 
Basically I'm trying to run an old example but I do not understand where I'm wrong

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

You have a migration mistake.

See: you use `Encoder` but specify it to the `value-serializer` which really requires `org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer` implementation.

So, or use `key(value)-encoder` for the `<int-kafka:producer-configuration>` configuration or wrap your Encoders with `EncoderAdaptingSerializer`.